# Unable to get the data in list view of API integration in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have tried to parse the JSON response to the list view in android app, But I am getting error as Json parsing error: No value for parent in my list as toast message in blank screen. Please help me to fix it.,Kindly help me.

My API response:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "node": {
        "parent": "",
        "title": "The Lofts",
        "field_location": "Jordan, Amman, Abdali",
        "field_image": "http://staging2.damacproperties.com/sites/default/files/styles/teaser_thumb/public/project/-/thelofts-big5.jpg?itok=InaluSKu",
        "body": "The Lofts is a Jordan real estate marvel, located at the gateway to the Abdali master plan.\nThese stunning apartments offer a unique lifestyle choice with homes that feature high ceilings and wide-open spaces, ideal for connoisseurs of modern living. Each apartment exudes elegant style and sense of freedom and every loft boasts its own expansive roof terrace with wonderful views of the surrounding neighbourhood.\n",
        "field_project_type": "",
        "field_amenities": "Cafes, Dining, Entertainment, Fitness, Open Roof Terraces, Parking, Security, Shopping, Spa, Swimming Pool",
        "field_community_info": "The Abdali project is the Jordanian capital’s all-new downtown area. It will provide a new central point that masterfully combines business, social and residential elements as well as leisure and entertainment facilities to offer a complete lifestyle destination for thousands of residents, visitors and investors alike.\n",
        "field_facilities": "\n24-hour concierge and help desk\nOpen roof terraces with every loft\nTemperature-controlled swimming pool\nJacuzzi\nSauna\nState-of-the-art gymnasium\nRestaurants\nCafés and juice bar\nRetail outlets\n\n",
        "field_image_gallery": [
          {
            "src": "http://staging2.damacproperties.com/sites/default/files/project/1137-the-lofts/gallery/the-lofts-1137-2548.jpg",
            "alt": ""
          },
          {
            "src": "http://staging2.damacproperties.com/sites/default/files/project/1137-the-lofts/gallery/the-lofts-1137-2549.jpg",
            "alt": ""
          },
          {
            "src": "http://staging2.damacproperties.com/sites/default/files/project/1137-the-lofts/gallery/the-lofts-1137-2550.jpg",
            "alt": ""
          },
          {
            "src": "http://staging2.damacproperties.com/sites/default/files/project/1137-the-lofts/gallery/the-lofts-1137-2551.jpg",
            "alt": "Above the Bed Blue Painting"
          },
          {
            "src": "http://staging2.damacproperties.com/sites/default/files/project/1137-the-lofts/gallery/the-lofts-1137-2552.jpg",
            "alt": ""
          },
          {
            "src": "http://staging2.damacproperties.com/sites/default/files/project/1137-the-lofts/gallery/the-lofts-1137-2553.jpg",
            "alt": ""
          },
          {
            "src": "http://staging2.damacproperties.com/sites/default/files/project/1137-the-lofts/gallery/the-lofts-1137-2554.jpg",
            "alt": ""
          },
          {
            "src": "http://staging2.damacproperties.com/sites/default/files/project/1137-the-lofts/gallery/the-lofts-1137-2555.jpg",
            "alt": ""
          },
          {
            "src": "http://staging2.damacproperties.com/sites/default/files/project/1137-the-lofts/gallery/the-lofts-1137-2556.jpg",
            "alt": ""
          },
          {
            "src": "http://staging2.damacproperties.com/sites/default/files/project/1137-the-lofts/gallery/the-lofts-1137-2557.jpg",
            "alt": ""
          }
        ],
        "field_location_1": "Jordan, Amman, Abdali",
        "field_map": "POINT(35.909645 31.963148)",
        "field_resource": "",
        "field_video": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://staging2.damacproperties.com/en/webservices/projects/1137";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                    JSONArray nodes = jsonObj.getJSONArray("nodes");


                    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = nodes.getJSONObject(i);

                        String parent = c.getString("parent");
                        String title = c.getString("title");
                        String field_location = c.getString("field_location");
                        String body = c.getString("body");
                        String field_project_type = c.getString("field_project_type");
                        String field_amenities = c.getString("field_amenities");
                        String field_community_info = c.getString("field_community_info");
                        String field_facilities = c.getString("field_facilities");

                        String field_location_1 = c.getString("field_location_1");
                        String field_map = c.getString("field_map");
                        String field_resource = c.getString("field_resource");
                        String field_video = c .getString("field_video");


                        HashMap<String, String> node = new HashMap<>();


                        node.put("parent", parent);
                        node.put("title", title);
                        node.put("field_location", field_location);
                        node.put("body", body);
                        node.put("field_project_type", field_project_type);
                        node.put("field_amenities", field_amenities);
                        node.put("field_community_info", field_community_info);
                        node.put("field_facilities", field_facilities);
                        node.put("field_location_1", field_location_1);
                        node.put("field_map", field_map);
                        node.put("field_resource", field_resource);
                        node.put("field_video",field_video);


                        myList.add(node);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, myList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"parent","title", "body","field_location","field_project_type","field_amenities","field_community_info","field_facilities","field_location_1","field_map","field_resource_video"
                    }, new int[]{R.id.parent,
                    R.id.title, R.id.field_location, R.id.body, R.id.field_project_type, R.id.field_amenities, R.id.field_community_info, R.id.field_facilities, R.id.field_location_1, R.id.field_map, R.id.field_resource, R.id.field_video});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

My logcat error:

```
05-15 13:41:22.451 9711-9876/com.example.agnitio18.myapplication E/MainActivity: Response from url: {"nodes":[{"node":{"parent":"","title":"The Lofts","field_location":"Jordan, Amman, Abdali","field_image":"http:\/\/staging2.damacproperties.com\/sites\/default\/files\/styles\/teaser_thumb\/public\/project\/-\/thelofts-big5.jpg?itok=InaluSKu","body":"The Lofts is a Jordan real estate marvel, located at the gateway to the Abdali master plan.\nThese stunning apartments offer a unique lifestyle choice with homes that feature high ceilings and wide-open spaces, ideal for connoisseurs of modern living. Each apartment exudes elegant style and sense of freedom and every loft boasts its own expansive roof terrace with wonderful views of the surrounding neighbourhood.\n","field_project_type":"","field_amenities":"Cafes, Dining, Entertainment, Fitness, Open Roof Terraces, Parking, Security, Shopping, Spa, Swimming Pool","field_community_info":"The Abdali project is the Jordanian capital\u2019s all-new downtown area. It will provide a new central point that masterfully combines business, social and residential elements as well as leisure and entertainment facilities to offer a complete lifestyle destination for thousands of residents, visitors and investors alike.\n","field_facilities":"\n24-hour concierge and help desk\nOpen roof terraces with every loft\nTemperature-controlled swimming pool\nJacuzzi\nSauna\nState-of-the-art gymnasium\nRestaurants\nCaf\u00e9s and juice bar\nRetail outlets\n\n","field_image_gallery":[{"src":"http:\/\/staging2.damacproperties.com\/sites\/default\/files\/project\/1137-the-lofts\/gallery\/the-lofts-1137-2548.jpg","alt":""},{"src":"http:\/\/staging2.damacproperties.com\/sites\/default\/files\/project\/1137-the-lofts\/gallery\/the-lofts-1137-2549.jpg","alt":""},{"src":"http:\/\/staging2.damacproperties.com\/sites\/default\/files\/project\/1137-the-lofts\/gallery\/the-lofts-1137-2550.jpg","alt":""},{"src":"http:\/\/staging2.damacproperties.com\/sites\/default\/files\/project\/1137-the-lofts\/gallery\/the-lofts-1137-2551.jpg","alt":"Above the Bed Blue Painting"},{"src":"http:\/\/staging2.damacproperties.com\/sites\/default\/files\/project\/1137-the-lofts\/gallery\/the-lofts-1137-2552.jpg","alt":""},{"src":"http:\/\/staging2.damacproperties.com\/sites\/default\/files\/project\/1137-the-lofts\/gallery\/the-lofts-1137-2553.jpg","alt":""},{"src":"http:\/\/staging2.damacproperties.com\/sites\/default\/files\/project\/1137-the-lofts\/gallery\/the-lofts-1137-2554.jpg","alt":""},{"src":"http:\/\/staging2.damacproperties.com\/sites\/default\/files\/project\/1137-the-lofts\/gallery\/the-lofts-1137-2555.jpg","alt":""},{"src":"http:\/\/staging2.damacproperties.com\/sites\/default\/files\/project\/1137-the-lofts\/gallery\/the-lofts-1137-2556.jpg","alt":""},{"src":"http:\/\/staging2.damacproperties.com\/sites\/default\/files\/project\/1137-the-lofts\/gallery\/the-lofts-1137-2557.jpg","alt":""}],"field_location_1":"Jordan, Amman, Abdali","field_map":"POINT(35.909645 31.963148)","field_resource":"","field_video":""}}]}
05-15 13:41:22.458 9711-9876/com.example.agnitio18.myapplication E/MainActivity: Json parsing error: No value for parent
```

Comment: it is `nodes[0]->node->parent` not `nodes[0]->parent` , please learn some json basics

Comment: @Selvin so where should i make changes now?

Comment: *so where should i make changes now?* isn't it obvious? you need to get "node" property of iteration item as iteration item has no "parent" property

Comment: hava a look at [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)! Dont do JSON with by your own hands. Create a [pojo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) out of the api response. Then simple put the pojo in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

you need to go one more step deeper in array..
change these lines as below..

```
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject b = nodes.getJSONObject(i);  // u need to put it here
        JSONObject c = b.getJSONObject("node"); // here getting node object

        String parent = c.getString("parent");
        String title = c.getString("title");
        ....
```

.....